# how to change the order of views in my iphone application?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiview

i have created an application but now i have added some other views in it and now i want to make the new view as my first page.....is it possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit your AppDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {        
// Override point for customization after application launch.
// Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
[window addSubview:viewController.view1];//you may add view2, view3
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You might need to provide a bit more details to get an accurate answer. Assuming you have multiple UIViews in a containing UIView, a few things to look at are:

UIView:

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view
- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view aboveSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index
```